# A problem of judge if a number contains '0' in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Actually, I am writing a code to judge whether a number contains any 0. The function name is haveZero. For example, haveZero(109) should return true and haveZero(211) should return false. This is the code I wrote but it seems that only the base case haveZero(0) and other numbers that ends with '0' can return true.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't post pictures of code, or links to them, paste in the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to use the standard `number_codes/2` predicate and the de facto standard `memberchk/2` predicate:

```
has_zero(Number) :-
    number_codes(Number, Codes),
    memberchk(0'0, Codes).
```

The `0'0` term is a standard number notation that allows us to get the code of the character following the `0'` prefix.

Sample calls:

```
| ?- has_zero(109).
yes

| ?- has_zero(211).
no
```

Answer (score 0):

`is` means assignment in prolog. Your code assign (a number mod 10) to 0, so just the number mod 10 is 0 (ends with 0) can be true.